# Expression of the error $E(f)$ according to the class of the function

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Sorry fory my bad english.

Let $f \in C^4([-1,1])$ a function. We want to calculate the Hermite polynomials at the points $x_0 = -1$ and $x_1 = 1$ and deduce an integration method. I found :

$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx \approx f(-1) + f(1) + \frac{1}{3} f'(-1) - \frac{1}{3} f'(1)$.

I would like to know how to estimate the error $E(f)$ of this method according to the class of the function f (here, f is $C^4$) ? It's a point that I didn't understand despite some lessons.
Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have an idea about the degree of the Hermite polynomials involved in the process ?

Comment: The dregree of the integration method is 3 ?